# search date from date time field query not working

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have below query

```
 sql_query = "select * from bericht where fromtime = " & Me.von & " and b_date = #" & Me.l_date & "#"
```

it print following line by debug.

```
select * from bericht where fromtime = 6 and b_date = #1/30/2020#
```

in table the `b_date` is `dateTime field`. ( **linked table from SQL server in Msaccess**)

in this table there is data exist with `1/30/2020 2:00:00 PM` where `fromtime` is also 6.

why query didn't return any data?

can msaccess cannot search date in datetime field?

PS: `fromtime` is intiger not time field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `#1/30/2020#` <> `1/30/2020 2:00:00 PM`.

Convert the column to a date, rather than a datetime, before you do the comparison.

```
... and DateValue(b_date) = #" & Me.l_date & "#"
```

This will return all rows from that date that meet your other condition.

Comment: it works. that means ms access didn't consider my values as date until i used DateValue.

Comment: No, that's not quite it. When comparing a date to a datetime, Access, and every other database that I'm aware of, assumes that the date has a time value of midnight. So you were comparing `1/30/2020 2:00:00 PM` to `1/30/2020 12:00:00 AM`. Those are different values, so there was no match. Using the `DateValue` function strips the time off of the value in the table and just compares the dates, ignoring the time component.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, consider searching all datetimes within the date range as `DateValue` can have efficiency issues:

```sql
select * from bericht 
where fromtime = 6 
  and b_date >= CDate("2020-01-30") 
  and b_date < CDate("2020-01-30") + 1
```

And to point directly to a form/report field. Save below as a stored query and call it as needed in VBA with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`:

```sql
select * from bericht 
where fromtime = Forms!myForm!von 
  and b_date >= [Forms!myForm!l_date]
  and b_date < ([Forms!myForm!l_date] + 1)
```

If using query for recordset builds, *still* use the preferred parameterization method and *still* use a stored query and in VBA open it with QueryDefs and bind needed [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao) at runtime:

**SQL**

```sql
parameters [myint] int, [mydate] date;
select * from bericht 
where fromtime = [myint] 
  and b_date >= [mydate]
  and b_date < ([mydate] + 1)
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim qDef As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef!myint = Me.von
qdef!myDate = Me.l_date

Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()

...
```